# How to compare multiple array items against one array item for word guessing script

Tags: php, function

I'm making a function that compares an array of items (characters) against another array containing a word. So far i have this function but it returns not found exept if i change the characters to one item identical to the `$randomWord` variable.

What I want is the function to compare all the array items in the `$correctLetters` array to the word in the `$randomWord` array and if there are more then i.e 3 matching characters i want it to guess the given word.

I can't seem to wrap my head around it since i've tried a lot f functions so far without succes.

```
$randomWord = ['fiets'];
$correctLetters = ['f', 'e', 's'];

//raad het woord 
function getWordBasedOnLetter($correctLetters, $randomWord)
{
    foreach ($correctLetters as $array) {
        if (in_array($array, $randomWord)) {
            return "found";
        }
    }
    return "not found";
}
```

Comment: If I am reading your loop correctly you are checking if 'f' is in $randomWord. This means you are making a comparison between 1 array element in $randomWord which is 'feits'. >>> 'feits' != 'f', thus you are not finding it. You need to split the string contained in each array element of $randomWord, and compare each of those characters to the array elements in $correctLetters. If you need such a loop, I would be happy to provide it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
array_diff(array1,array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to split the random word into characters, and then use [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to find the matching characters between that and the set of correct letters. If the count of that array is >= 3, the word has been found:

```
function getWordBasedOnLetter($correctLetters, $randomWord)
{
    $randomLetters = str_split($randomWord);
    $matchingLetters = array_intersect($correctLetters, $randomLetters);
    if (count($matchingLetters) >= 3) {
        return "found";
    }
    return "not found";
}
```

For your sample data this outputs `found`. [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rhGvK)

**Update**

If you want to make the test based on the length of the random word, it is probably better to use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) as that will work better when there are duplicated letters in `$randomWord`. In this case, set the test to be the number of non-matching letters to be less than a threshold of the length of the word (e.g. 40%):

```
function getWordBasedOnLetter($correctLetters, $randomWord)
{
    $randomLetters = str_split($randomWord);
    $differentLetters = array_diff($randomLetters, $correctLetters);
    if (count($differentLetters) < .4 * strlen($randomWord)) {
        return "found";
    }
    return "not found";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/K5Rvm)

Comment: Thanks @Nick! This really helps, only one thing. This function is a part of a larger piece of code and one thing that comes with it is that there will be random words of different lengths. How do is adapt count >= to the length of a word or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: @JeremyStam you could make the comparison a function of the length of `$randomWord` e.g. `count($matchingLetters) >= .6 * strlen($randomWord)`

Comment: Awesome! Going to try that!

Comment: @JeremyStam had some more thoughts on this overnight. See my edit.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but the problem doesn't seen to get fixed since I'm stuck with a little glitch.

Comment: @JeremyStam what issue are you having?